# PMF of the sum of two independent random variables with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I'm working through the problem below:

**Q:** Let $X∼Poisson(α)$ and $Y∼Poisson(β)$ be two independent random variables. Define a new random variable as $Z=X+Y$. Find the PMF of $Z$.

**A:** $$
\begin{aligned}
P_Z(k) & =P(X+Y=k) \\
& =\sum_{i=0}^k P(X+Y=k \mid X=i) P(X=i) \quad \text { (law of total probability) } \\
& =\sum_{i=0}^k P(Y=k-i \mid X=i) P(X=i) \quad \quad \quad \text { (since } X \text { and } Y \text { are independent) } \\
& =\sum_{i=0}^k P(Y=k-i) P(X=i) \quad \\
& =\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{e^{-\beta} \beta^{k-i}}{(k-i) !} \frac{e^{-\alpha} \alpha^i}{i !} \\
& =e^{-(\alpha+\beta)} \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\alpha^i \beta^{k-i}}{(k-i) ! i !} \\
& =\frac{e^{-(\alpha+\beta)}}{k !} \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{k !}{(k-i) i !} \alpha^i \beta^{k-i} \\
& =\frac{e^{-(\alpha+\beta)}}{k !} \sum_{i=0}^k\left(\begin{array}{c}
k \\
i
\end{array}\right) \alpha^i \beta^{k-i} \\
& =\frac{e^{-(\alpha+\beta)}}{k !}(\alpha+\beta)^k \quad \quad \text { (by the binomial theorem). }
\end{aligned}
$$

I can follow the algbraic manipulations, but my question is how on earth can I come up with the solution in the first place? Seeing the solution makes sense but it's like if you have a hammer everything looks like a nail. What is the intuition here to start with the fact that I have to expand using the LOTP and then express the first expression in terms of Y, and only then substitute with the Poisson PMF.

Or am I just overthinking it and it is just a "trick" that needs to be learned by heart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a mix of everything, knowing tricks and knowing where to start. To make it a little more intuitive you can do this
\begin{align}
P(Z =k) & = \sum_{x} P(Z = k, X = x)
\end{align*}
true? yes! because we are marginalized $X$, but here the trick is that we know what $Z$ is, so

\begin{align*}
P(Z =k) & = \sum_{x} P(Z = k, X = x)\tag{1} \\
& = \sum_{x} P(X+Y = k, X = x)  \\
& = \sum_{x} P(Y = k - X, X = x) \\
& = \sum_{x} P(Y = k - x, X = x) \\
& = \sum_{x} P(Y = k - x)P( X = x) 
\end{align*}

and from now on it is the same as what you suggest.

Comment: Can I make sure I understand your first expression. We are saying the probability that random variable $Z$ (which is known to have a Poisson dist) takes on value $k$ is the sum of the probabilities that $Z$ takes on $k$ and that r.v. $X$ takes on value $x$ for all possible values of $x.$ What is the justification for this? I can sense the intuition being something like because $Z = X + Y $ for all Y and X, so breaking it down to individual probabilities of $X=x$ makes no difference.

Comment: You say the justification of $(1)$? is the definition of Marginalization, in the continuos case $$f_{X}(x) =  \int_{Support(Y) } f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy $$ and in the discrete case  $$p_{X}(x) =  \sum_{Support(Y) } p_{X,Y}(x,y)  $$

Comment: Ah interesting. I have not heard of marginalisation. I’ll have a read.